# Android Error with a Json File - E/FetchWeatherTask﹕ Error

Tags: android, android-json

I'm getting an error trying to get a json file.

Json:

> http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7

Error:

```
04-25 04:12:32.086    3875-3897/com.example.g250.dublinweather.app E/FetchWeatherTask﹕ Error
```

Code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

            //Debugging
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Json String" + forecastJsonStr);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

There is a problem with the json file, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Someone who can help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: I also had this problem. json is displayed in webbrowser but not in the application. My problem was that the server and administrator to resolve this problem. My question is with the [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874205/getting-json-works-on-localhost-and-some-websites-but-not-working-on-my-real-se) in my account.

Answer (score 0):

Just use volley for your json requests is plain simple (See here for [volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)) and here for [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide). In order to include them add the following into your gradle build file

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
```

This is the example of code to make a json request via volley. Much Simpler

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlJson,
        (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

  @Override
  public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

    try {
      // Parsing json object response
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      // Do your stuff here to parse it in your model
     }catch (Exception e) {
        // log here your error 
     }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

  @Override
  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    VolleyLog.d(LOGTAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
    Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error while executing getNetworkFeed");
  }
});

// Adding request to request queue
getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

}

Comment: Well I I'know who to use it, but I really would like fix the problem and know what it's happening. Anyway thanks!